# how to use FilterSet in django with date field

Tags: python, html, django

I have a `dat_transacao` field and I'd like to create a range with it, but it didn't work. I created `dat_inicial` and `dat_final` in `filters.py`, but the screen didn't filter the records by these fields. Something is wrong but I don't know what is it. Anyone can help me please?
Thanks.

models.py:

```
class transacao(models.Model):
    dat_transacao = models.DateTimeField('Geração da Transação', auto_now=True)
    pessoa = models.ForeignKey(pessoa, default='', blank=True, null=True) # Chave estrangeira da Classe Pessoa
    tipotransacao = models.ForeignKey(tipotransacao, default='', blank=True, null=True) # Chave estrangeira da Classe Tipo de Transação
    servico = models.ForeignKey(servico, default='', blank=True, null=True) # Chave estrangeira da Classe Servico (que pode ser NULL)
    bloco = models.ForeignKey(bloco, default='', blank=True, null=True) # Chave estrangeira da Classe Bloco
```

filters.py:

```
from .models import *
import django_filters
#from django_filters import DateTimeFilter

class livrorazaoFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    dat_inicial = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(name='dat_transacao',lookup_type=('gte'))
    dat_final = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(name='dat_transacao',lookup_type=('lte'))

    class Meta:
        model = transacao
        fields = ['dat_inicial', 'dat_final', 'tipotransacao', 'pessoa', 'bloco']
```

views.py

```
def transacao_livrorazao(request, id=None):
    instancia_transacao = transacao.objects.all().order_by('-dat_transacao')
    instancia_transacaofilter = livrorazaoFilter(request.GET, queryset=instancia_transacao)
    context = {
            "queryset": instancia_transacao,
            "filter": instancia_transacaofilter,
            "instancia_transacao": instancia_transacao
    }
    return render(request, 'livrorazao/livrorazao.html', context)
```

livrorazao.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr">

        <form class=" bd-form-2 " action="#" name="form-name" method="get">
            {% csrf_token %}

        <p>Período</p>
        <p>De</p>
            <input type="date" name='filter.form.dat_inicial' id="dat_inicial"  class="bd-form-input" >
        <p>até</p>
            <input type="date" name='filter.form.dat_final' id="dat_final"  class="bd-form-input" >
        <p>Tipo de Transação</p>
             {{ filter.form.tipotransacao }}

         <button type="submit">Consultar</button>
        </form>

        <br>
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
        <tbody><tr>
            <th>ID Transação</th>
            <th>Data/Hora</th>
            <th>TipoTransação</th>
            <th>Blockchain</th>
        </tr>

      {% for instance in filter.qs  %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ instance.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ instance.dat_transacao }}</td>
            <td>{{ instance.tipotransacao }}</td>
            <!--<td>{{ instance.pessoa }}</td>-->
            <td>{{ instance.bloco }}</td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}

</tbody></table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

my solution is similar to what @cezar posted. However, changing `attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}` to `attrs={'type': 'date'`} was what worked for me.

my frontend form display is managed using [django-widget-tweaks](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks)

Here is an extract of what works for me:

## models.py

```
class Applications(models.Model):
    #...
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

## filters.py

```
from .models import Applications
import django_filters

class ApplicationFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    start_date = django_filter.DateTimeFromRangeFilter(widget=django.widgets.RangeWidget(
    attrs={'type': 'date'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Applications
        fields = ['status', 'start_date']
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Applications
from .filters import ApplicationFilter

def application_search(request):
    #... I stripped the view function down to what concerns filters.py
    application_list = Application.objects.all()
    application_filter = ApplicationFilter(request.GET, queryset=application_list)

    return render(
        request,
        "applications.html,
        {'filter': application_filter}
    )
```

## applications.html (with bootstrap)

```
...
{% load bootstrap4 %}{% load widget_tweaks %}
<form method="GET" class="form-inline">
<div class=form-group>
<label style="margin-right: 20px">Filter: </label>
{% render_field filter.form.status class="form-control"%}
<label style="margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 10px;">From </label>
{% render_field filter.form.start_date class="form-control" %}
<button style="margin-left: 10px" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">
 GO
</button>
</div>
</form>
...
```

P.S: By default, I'd added `django_filters` to settings.py

[Here's how the form looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acQoT.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `DateFromToRangeFilter`. Instead of `dat_inicial` and `dat_final` add this snippet to your `FilterSet` class:

```
dat_transacao = django_filters.DateTimeFromToRangeFilter()
```

This filter should create two input fields and query for entries having values between the lower and upper limit. By passing further arguments you can modify the look and behaviour, for example add datepicker:

```
dat_transacao = django_filters.DateTimeFromToRangeFilter(
    widget=django_filters.widgets.RangeWidget(
        attrs={'class': 'datepicker'}
    )
)
```

Adapt after that your HTML template as needed. Basically it should work with these lines:

```
<form class="bd-form-2 " action="" name="form-name" method="get">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ filter.form }}
    <button type="submit">Consultar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks. I included dat_transacao = django_filters.DateTimeFromToRangeFilter() and removed dat_inicial and dat_final. My HTML was like that <input type="date" name='filter.form.dat_transacao' id="dat_transacao" class="bd-form-input" >, but it didn´t work, it didn´t create two fields.

Comment: It didn´t work: Error during template rendering
In template C:\GROWTHTECH\Projetos\blockchain\transacao\templates\testes\livrorazao2.html, error at line 7

django_filters/widgets/multiwidget.html

Comment: I got it !!! It worked when i include 'django_filters' on INSTALLED_APPS and {{filter.form.dat_transacao}} in html. But it didn´t work when i include <input type="date" name='filter.form.dat_transacao'  class="bd-form-input" >

Comment: Yes, you have to to include `django_filters` in `INSTALLED_APPS`. In the example from your second sentence `name="filter.form.dat_transacao"` can't work. You must enclose template variables in double curly brace (`{{ filter.form.dat_transacao }}`). But, as I said, you should be able to render the filter form with `{{ filter.form }}`. If this generic approach doesn't meet your needs, you can render the form fields manually.

Comment: yes. i update to this: <input type="date" name="{{ filter.form.dat_transacao }}" value="dat_transacao"  class="bd-form-input" >. In this case, the first date is ok, but the second one didn´t work because didn´t display a input date type.